# How to change gridview cell color based on cell value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have grid in that we are getting pivot table from my sql database .now I need to give different colors to gridview cell according to their cell value.Please help me out for c# code for this requirement.

```
----------------------------------------------- 
Alternative Goal 1  Goal 2  Goal 3  Goal 4
-----------------------------------------------
A           0.86    0.5      1   0.5      
B           0.87    0   0.9      0.6      
----------------------------------------------
```

now colour according to value will be like below

```
Value                 Colour Code
----------------------------------
1.00                   33B739
0.75 to 0.99            50EB19
0.50 to 0.74            54EA58
0.25 to 0.49            93FB85
0.05 to 0.24            E0FCE0
0.00                    FFFFFF
-0.24 to -0.05          FFD5D5
-0.49 to -0.25          FFA3A3
-0.74 to -0.50          FF6161
-0.99 to -0.75          FF3333
-1.00                   FF0000
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Try to store it in any #temp table then retrieve value using between clause or >/< operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but I would do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<ColorMap> colorMaps = new List<ColorMap>()
        {
            new ColorMap(-999, -1, "FF0000"),
            new ColorMap(-0.99, -0.75, "FF3333")
            /* and so on*/
        };

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
                double cellValue;
                if (!double.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out cellValue)) {
                    continue;//or whatever logic you want
                }
                ColorMap colorMap = colorMaps.SingleOrDefault(x => x.From <= cellValue && x.To >= cellValue);
                if (colorMap == null) {
                    continue;//or whatever logic you want
                }

                ColorCode colorCode = new ColorCode(colorMap.Value);
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(colorCode.Red, colorCode.Green, colorCode.Blue);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ColorMap {
    public double From { get; private set; }//lowest border
    public double To { get; private set; }//highest border
    public string Value { get; private set; }//color code

    public ColorMap(double from, double to, string value) {
        this.From = @from;
        this.To = to;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class ColorCode {
    public string Color { get; private set; }

    public ColorCode(string code) {
        this.Color = code;
    }

    public int Red { get { return ConvertToInt(0, 1); } }
    public int Green { get { return ConvertToInt(2, 3); } }
    public int Blue { get { return ConvertToInt(4, 5); } }

    private int ConvertToInt(int index1, int index2) {
        if (Color == null || Color.Length != 6) {
            return 0;//or whatever logic you want
        }
        string hexValue = string.Format("{0}{1}", Color[index1], Color[index2]);
        int result;
        try {
            result = int.Parse(hexValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        } catch {
            return 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I hope your database table has separate fields for both lowest value and highest, since it would be easier to read it.

Comment: thx for your reply but my I will use these colour values only in condition. These max and min values are not mentioned in db.